# Individual Subqueries are fast. Adding 1 Subquery is fast. However, adding more than 1 Subquery together crashes MySQL. How to fix?

Tags: mysql, crash, subquery, pivot-table, query-optimization

I have the following query to select users who have posted at least once each week for the past 4 weeks:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM `posts` WHERE

    user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM `posts` WHERE post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*0) ) - 604800) AND post_date <= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*0))) AND
    user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM `posts` WHERE post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*1) ) - 604800) AND post_date <= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*1))) AND
    user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM `posts` WHERE post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*2) ) - 604800) AND post_date <= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*2))) AND
    user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM `posts` WHERE post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*3) ) - 604800) AND post_date <= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*3)))
```

If I run the query with just 1 of *any* of those 4 sub-queries, it is fast.

If I run any of those 4 sub-queries *individually*, they are fast.

However, the moment I add *more than 1* of those subqueries *together*, MySQL hangs.

How can I fix this so it works considering the individual parts are fast?

(I should add that in this particular case, I cannot add any more indexes, so the solution should not involve indexing).

Comment: Did you try using OR instead of AND

Comment: No, because the query is supposed to find users who have posted **each week** for the past 4 weeks, not users who posted *any week* in the last 4 weeks.

Comment: *Crashes MySql?* Would you be willing to tell us more about what happens exactly? (I personally do some reliability engineering and am always interested in learning what can cause crashes and what they look like.)

Comment: What datatype is `post_date`?

Comment: @O.Jones "crashes" was perhaps hyperbolic.  When I run it in phpmyadmin, it hangs and eventually ends up with a CloudFlare error.  So perhaps it may not be crashing MySQL and just taking too long.

Comment: @RickJames `post_date` is `unsigned int(10)`

Comment: Aha. Your query *timed out*.  Understood. The word *crashes* is a red flag  to operations people. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @O.Jones you are absolutely right and I should have been more accurate with my language, sorry about the false alarm!  Did you get a chance to fix the syntax error in your answer below?  I can't figure out what's wrong and haven't been able to run it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to `EXPLAIN <query>` to see the execution plan, each subquery could read many rows of data.

But I suggest to re-write the query for this particular purpose, it needs to `GROUP BY` user and `COUNT DISTINCT` weeks as 4, read the table once is sufficient.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM `posts` 
WHERE post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*3) ) - 604800)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT 
    (CASE WHEN post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*0) ) - 604800) AND post_date <= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*0)) THEN 1
        WHEN post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*1) ) - 604800) AND post_date <= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*1)) THEN 2
        WHEN post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*2) ) - 604800) AND post_date <= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*2)) THEN 3
        ELSE 4 END)) = 4
```

**About the query**

- `WHERE post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (604800*3) ) - 604800)` filter applicable data only
- `CASE WHEN post_date > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP ...` transform the `post_date` into week 1, 2, 3 or 4

Now if there are data like below

```
+---------+------+
| user_id | week |
+---------+------+
|       1 |    1 |
|       1 |    2 |
|       1 |    3 |
|       1 |    3 |
|       2 |    1 |
|       2 |    2 |
|       2 |    3 |
|       2 |    4 |
+---------+------+
```

There are four rows for each `user_id`, but user 1 appears in week 1,2,3, `COUNT DISTINCT week` is 3, user 2 will count 4

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain this query?  It's intriguing and completely different to my query and I'm trying to make sense of it.

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl added a short explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to do this in one pass through all those `posts` rows. Here's a suggestion.

I assume your `post_date` column is some kind of number, not a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

First, we need an expression to determine how many weeks ago each post occurred. That's this. It yields an integer. 0 for posts less than a week old, 1 for posts between one and two weeks old etc.

```
TRUNCATE( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_time ) / 608400, 0)
```

Next we need a subquery to count posts and users by week.

```
    SELECT 
     COUNT(*) post_count,
     user_id,
     TRUNCATE((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_time ) / 608400, 0) age
    FROM posts
   WHERE date_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (4 * 608400)
     AND date_time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    GROUP BY user_id, age
```

This result set contains one row for each user_id and week.

Finally, summarize the subquery and use  HAVING to choose user_id values that show up in it four times.

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM ( /* that subquery goes here */ ) ages
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

This is efficient because it can gather all four weeks' work of data from the `posts` table in one scan.  If you happen to have an index on `(date_time, user_id)` MySql does it with an index scan and it will be surprisingly fast.

It's also sweet if your requirement changes to, say, six weeks. Change the `4` constants to `6` and you can use the same query.

Putting it together:

```
SELECT user_id FROM (
  SELECT 
     COUNT(*) post_count,
     user_id,
     TRUNCATE((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_time) / 608400, 0) age
    FROM posts
   WHERE date_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (4 * 608400)
     AND date_time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    GROUP BY user_id, age
   ) ages
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a #1064 syntax error when running your code.  Can you please fix it so I can test it?

Comment: Any luck fixing this error?  I can't figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Darn it! MySQL quirk. No spaces allowed between function names `COUNT` and parameters `COUNT(*)`.  Fixed.  I was away from my desktop machine when I answered your question. For information about troubleshooting syntax errors [please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql-error-1064/info).

Answer (score 1):

Let's flip things around.  Will starting with this be more useful?

```
SELECT  weeks.weeks_old,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users
    FROM (
        SELECT  user_id,
                (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - post_date) / 604800 AS weeks_old
            FROM ...
         ) AS weeks
    GROUP BY  weeks_old;
```

It may need a second step to "pivot-table".

Comment: Thanks, but I get a `#1054 - Unknown column 'weeks_old' in 'field list'` error when running your code.  Can you please fix it so I can test it?

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl - Fixed (I hope)

Comment: Thanks, but it's still giving me an error:  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.weeks_old
            FROM posts
         ) AS weeks
    GROUP BY  weeks_o' at line 5`

Comment: Maybe this time.  Please note that I did not finish filling out the `FROM`